# Rundeck not able connect the domain servers

Tags: rundeck

I am running Rundeck 3.0.20-20190408 in Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 and I am connecting the node using pem key.

resource.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project>
        <node name="10.10.101.100" description="MyServer" tags="" hostname="10.10.101.100" osArch="amd64" osFamily="unix" osName="Linux" osVersion="3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.x86_64" username="rundeckuser" ssh-keypath="/home/username@domain.com/rundeckuser.pem" />
</project>
```

Getting below error while executing the commands

> Execution failed: 3138 in project test_default: [Workflow result: ,
> step failures: {1=Dispatch failed on 1 nodes: [10.10.101.100:
> ConfigurationFailure: SSH Keyfile does not exist:
> /home/username@domain.com/rundeckuser.pem +
> {dataContext=MultiDataContextImpl(map={}, base=null)} ]}, Node
> failures: {10.10.101.100=[ConfigurationFailure: SSH Keyfile does not
> exist: /home/username@domain.com/rundeckuser.pem +
> {dataContext=MultiDataContextImpl(map={}, base=null)} ]}, status:
> failed]

Answer (score 0):

`ssh-keypath` must be defined with a local path reachable by `rundeck` user (or the user that launches Rundeck if you're using a [WAR](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/install/jar.html) based installation), like this [example](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/projects/node-execution/ssh.html#ssh-private-key-passphrase-with-a-job-option).

But the best approach is to use the Rundeck's key storage (adding the rundeck server public key to your target servers to access it, follow [this](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/6022#issuecomment-624678947) if you like). Also, you can see the best practices [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qOA-kWse22g) (it's using Rundeck 2.11 but is the same principle for all versions.